# How can I drop a packet with SharpPacp using WinDivert driver?

Tags: .net, sharppcap, packet-injection

I know SharpPcap is mainly developed for packet sniffing not modifying or filtering, but now I can see in its repository that WinDivert is going to be added into project but couldn't find any documentation.

How can I tell SharpPcap to use that WinDivert and how can I drop a packet by it?
Is there any equivalent driver in SharpPcap for intercepting and modifying packet for linux?